# Drawing Rounded Corners Using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uibezierpath

I have a design element that I'm having trouble figuring out; hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction.  The element I am trying to build is like so;

[image: Rounded Button With No Bottom Border]

Effectively, it's a rounded rectangle with a stroke on the left, top, and right sides (the bottom should have no stroke).

I've dabbled in using the following code;

```
// Create the rounded rectangle
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4.0, height: 4.0))

// Setup a shape layer
let shape = CAShapeLayer()

// Create the shape path
shape.path = maskPath.cgPath

// Apply the mask
myView.layer.mask = shape
```

Subsequently, I'm using the following to draw the stroke around the rect;

```
// Add border
let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
borderLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
borderLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
borderLayer.frame = self.bounds
self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

This results in the following image;

[image: Rounded Rect with Stroke]

I've not been able to figure out how to either *remove the bottom stroke* or *draw the item using a UIBezierPath()*, but rounding the corners in a way that would be identical to the rounded rect (I'm using another rounded rect in the same view for a different purpose, and the rounded corners would need to be identical).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a shape layer. Use a layer (or a view). Draw the UIBezierPath's path into it and stroke it, and then erase the bottom line by drawing it and stroking it with a `.clear` blend mode.

Result:

[image]

Code (modify as desired; I use here a clear UIView that draws the shape as its `draw` code):

```
let p = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                     byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight],
                     cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4.0, height: 4.0))
UIColor.white.setStroke()
p.stroke()
let p2 = UIBezierPath()
p2.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:self.bounds.height))
p2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:self.bounds.width, y:self.bounds.height))
p2.lineWidth = 2
p2.stroke(with: .clear, alpha: 1)
```

**EDIT** Another way would have been to clip out the bottom line area before drawing the rounded rect:

```
let p1 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin:.zero,
                                   size:CGSize(width:self.bounds.width, height:self.bounds.height-2)))
p1.addClip()
let p = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                     byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight],
                     cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 4.0, height: 4.0))
UIColor.white.setStroke()
p.stroke()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thanks, @matt!  I was overcomplicating this way too much; I didn't realize I could stroke with a `.clear` blend mode.  Makes sense now!

Comment: There is another way, which is to clip before drawing the rounded rect. Maybe I should have shown that too.

Comment: Added code to demonstrate the second way, clipping. I actually like clipping better in this case; it's easier to control.

Answer (score 10):

The `CGMutablePath` method `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)` is designed to make round corners easily.

```
extension CGMutablePath {
    static func bottomlessRoundedRect(in rect: CGRect, radius: CGFloat) -> CGMutablePath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY), radius: radius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY), radius: radius)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        return path
    }
}
```

Once you have that method, it's best to use a custom view to manage the `CAShapeLayer` so it can adapt to size changes automatically. Demo:

```
class MyFrameView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let layer = self.layer as! CAShapeLayer
        layer.lineWidth = 2
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.fillColor = nil
        layer.path = CGMutablePath.bottomlessRoundedRect(in: bounds.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10), radius: 8)
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 60))
view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7034167647, green: 0.4845994711, blue: 0.6114708185, alpha: 1)
let frameView = MyFrameView(frame: view.bounds)
frameView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(frameView)
let label = UILabel(frame: view.bounds)
label.text = "Hello"
label.textColor = .white
label.textAlignment = .center
view.addSubview(label)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Result:

[image: demo]

Comment: I'm glad you added this. We used to do this all the time back before bezier paths had automatic rounded corners! The only reason that I didn't use it here was that I wanted to stick with the exact bezier path the OP had started with, since that was part of the stipulation in the question.

Comment: You can't believe how glad i am to find this. Would give you bounty if i had chance. Thanks very much.