# How to get the dynamic distance between 2 elements in iOS with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, user-interface

I have this following UI that needs to draw a dashed line. I'm not sure how to calculate the width needed especially with the autolayout dynamically determining the spacing by screen. The green bars are single `UITableViewCells`. Below is the code for drawing the dashed line:

```
extension UIView {

    func addDashedBorder(barWidth: Int, maxWidth: Int) {
        //Create a CAShapeLayer
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        // passing an array with the values [2,3] sets a dash pattern that alternates between a 2-user-space-unit-long painted segment and a 3-user-space-unit-long unpainted segment
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [2,3]

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                                CGPoint(x: barWidth - maxWidth, y: 0)])
        shapeLayer.path = path
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

[image]

I need the red lines to overlap with the gray line. How would I do that given that finding the width of the gray line is inconsistent due to the when the delegate functions are called? I am currently attempting to get the width through the `didMoveToSuperview` method with no luck

Comment: Your best bet is to subclass a `UIView` and update the layer path by implementing `layoutSubviews()`. Then you can set your desired constraints on that view. Your description and image do not quite make clear where you want the red dotted line to go... if you post another image clearly showing how you ***want*** it to look, you can get a little more help.

Comment: How do you draw the gray line?

Comment: @robmayoff it's a `UIView` with height=1 and leading and trailing constraints set to zero between the label and bar

Comment: @DonMag I want the line to be between label and green bar without overlap. As you can see in the 2nd bar, the UIView clips to the center of those 2 dynamically based on the width of the bar. I would like to capture the true width post-constraint handling on my XIB cells of the gray line which is a `UIView` of height 1

Comment: @btrballin - sorry... you want the green bar to start at left and extend a certain width... then you want the gray bar to go from right-edge of green bar and stop before label... then you want red-dotted-bar to go from right-edge of green bar - *covering the gray bar( - and extending over the labels to the far right-edge of the cell?

Comment: Yeah exactly. In my screenshot the red dashed lines are overlapping with the label. I want their width to be end of green bar to start of label.

Comment: @btrballin - is this what you're going for? https://imgur.com/a/F9EBDDZ

Comment: Yessir. My method above takes care of the drawing portion of the line, but I'm having trouble passing in the right width to draw it to the right stage due to the UI not having been rendered yet from the auto layout constraints. If there is a lifecycle method post autolayout for a `UITableViewCell` then I'd be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to approach this.

One option... instead of drawing only the red-dotted line as a shape layer, draw the gray line, the red-dotted line and the green bar as 3 sub-layers.

- Bottom layer: gray line
- Middle layer: red-dotted line
- Top layer: green "bar" line

Since the green bar will be covering the red-dots and the gray line, those can each span the full width between the left edge of the cell and the left edge of the first label. That means the only piece that needs to change size is the green bar layer.

Here is some example code:

```
class MyProgressBarView: UIView {

    var progress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    let greenBar = CAShapeLayer()
    let grayBar = CAShapeLayer()
    let redBar = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        layer.addSublayer(grayBar)
        layer.addSublayer(redBar)
        layer.addSublayer(greenBar)

        redBar.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        redBar.lineWidth = 2
        // passing an array with the values [2,3] sets a dash pattern that alternates between a 2-user-space-unit-long painted segment and a 3-user-space-unit-long unpainted segment
        redBar.lineDashPattern = [2,3]

        grayBar.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        grayBar.lineWidth = 1

        greenBar.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height * 0.5),
                                CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height * 0.5)])

        grayBar.path = path
        redBar.path = path

        path = CGMutablePath()

        // cell height may change, so set greenBar's height here
        greenBar.lineWidth = bounds.height

        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height * 0.5),
                                CGPoint(x: bounds.width * progress, y: bounds.height * 0.5)])

        greenBar.path = path

    }
}

class ProgressCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var val1Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var val2Label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var progView: MyProgressBarView!

    var val1: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            val1Label.text = "\(val1)"
            // make sure we don't divide by Zero
            progView.progress = val2 > 0 ? val1 / val2 : 0.0
        }
    }
    var val2: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            val2Label.text = "$\(val2)M"
            // make sure we don't divide by Zero
            progView.progress = val2 > 0 ? val1 / val2 : 0.0
        }
    }

}

struct MyValues {
    var v1: CGFloat = 0.0
    var v2: CGFloat = 0.0
}

class ProgressTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myData: [MyValues] = [
        MyValues(v1:  50.0, v2: 250.0),
        MyValues(v1:  80.0, v2: 250.0),
        MyValues(v1: 105.0, v2: 250.0),
        MyValues(v1: 127.0, v2: 250.0),
        MyValues(v1:  93.0, v2: 250.0),
        MyValues(v1:  80.0, v2: 250.0),
        MyValues(v1: 205.0, v2: 250.0),
        MyValues(v1: 177.0, v2: 250.0),
        MyValues(v1: 245.0, v2: 250.0),
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgressCell", for: indexPath) as! ProgressCell
        let d = myData[indexPath.row]
        cell.val1 = d.v1
        cell.val2 = d.v2
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProgressCell {
            let d = myData[indexPath.row]
            var v = d.v1 + 10.0
            v = min(v, d.v2)
            myData[indexPath.row].v1 = v
            c.val1 = v
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the Storyboard source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15702" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="jKi-p9-QPh">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15704"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Progress Table View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="XK3-bb-mGO">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="xPK-h1-D8d" customClass="ProgressTableViewController" customModule="scratchy" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" id="Ofl-mQ-aYH">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="ProgressCell" id="hIa-mP-rya" customClass="ProgressCell" customModule="scratchy" customModuleProvider="target">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="43.5"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="hIa-mP-rya" id="fVi-sL-ouy">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="43.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1va-uW-uvw" customClass="MyProgressBarView" customModule="scratchy" customModuleProvider="target">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="11" width="187" height="21.5"/>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                        </view>
                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="150" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UNh-No-HjD">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="211" y="11" width="50" height="21.5"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="50" id="ziy-02-rwL"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="$30.45M" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aDM-ad-OT7">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="269" y="11" width="90" height="21.5"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="90" id="cMB-Uy-RTf"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstItem="1va-uW-uvw" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="fVi-sL-ouy" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="BVh-vs-fur"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="UNh-No-HjD" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="1va-uW-uvw" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="Fh8-Nf-sU3"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="aDM-ad-OT7" secondAttribute="trailing" id="GC9-ua-CdP"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="1va-uW-uvw" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="fVi-sL-ouy" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="Mg5-6e-QBM"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="aDM-ad-OT7" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="fVi-sL-ouy" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="YCc-VG-5rv"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="UNh-No-HjD" secondAttribute="bottom" id="bJG-Mk-j6m"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="UNh-No-HjD" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="fVi-sL-ouy" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="eKv-UH-Opf"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="aDM-ad-OT7" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="UNh-No-HjD" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="laQ-5R-RZa"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="1va-uW-uvw" secondAttribute="bottom" id="loG-KQ-7xC"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="aDM-ad-OT7" secondAttribute="bottom" id="wml-fK-ewt"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="progView" destination="1va-uW-uvw" id="Ips-T7-vZ5"/>
                                    <outlet property="val1Label" destination="UNh-No-HjD" id="Gqe-bP-u0c"/>
                                    <outlet property="val2Label" destination="aDM-ad-OT7" id="gMP-5N-FIb"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="xPK-h1-D8d" id="iaK-Nh-quP"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="xPK-h1-D8d" id="1qh-e9-C6l"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="Gie-Xj-DLT"/>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="9As-Tc-u8W" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="357.60000000000002" y="2048.7256371814096"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="k92-RW-oNV">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="jKi-p9-QPh" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="HPb-es-8az">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="xPK-h1-D8d" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="QXa-oP-Nwz"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="vwe-Vd-YNO" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-581.60000000000002" y="2048.7256371814096"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

The result:

[image]

and, with the device rotated, so you can see it automatically handles the size change - no special code for that:

[image]

If you add this to a new project and run it, I've also implemented `didSelectRowAt` -- each time you tap a row, it will increase the "left value" by `10.0` so you can see the green bar grow dynamically.

Comment: Another quick solution was to clip to bounds so that even if I draw more dotted lines than needed, it will not be visible anyways

Comment: @btrballin - after thinking about it, it could be eve simpler. Since the green-bar-view is on top, the gray-line and dotted-line views can stretch the full width anyway. All you'd need to do is change the width of the green-bar-view.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can already lay out a view (the gray bar) exactly how you want, one way to solve this is to use a view to draw the dotted red line. You can make a new subclass of `UIView` that uses a `CAShapeLayer` as its layer, and set up the path and stroking parameters in the custom class’s `layoutSubviews` method. I have demonstrated how to do this sort of thing (but not this exact thing) in other answers:

- [drawing a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52233438/77567)
- [drawing an animated arc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455882/77567)
- [drawing a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742234/77567)
- [drawing a partial border with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440180/77567)
- [drawing a tag-shaped background under text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55941523/77567)

Comment: My main focus is not on the drawing of the dashed line but how I can draw it in a manner that makes it in appear in between the bar and label. Give that thing is in a separate nib, is there a method call or delegate method where it will let me access the true width of the gray line under it?